# ruby / rails: TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update my Representation attributes ivpn & idirect (from a csv file via rake task but i just print here only the meat of the program) and getting the TypeError:

```
# in Rails Console:
representation = Representation.where(id: 977)
# => Representation_id: 977, ivnp: false, idirect: false

rows = Hash.[:ivpn => "", :idirect => "x"] # originally rows are coming from csv-file

representation.update_attributes! ivpn: rows.any?{|r| r[:ivpn].present?}, idirect: rows.any? {|r| r[:idirect].present?}

TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
        from (irb):42:in `[]'
        from (irb):42:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):42:in `each'
        from (irb):42:in `any?'
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: You have string keys `"ivpn" "idirect"` in your hash declaration, but symbols in the `any?`  blocks `:ivpn` and `:idirect`. Be consistent.  Is `rows` supposed to be one Hash or an Array of Hashes?

Comment: As a Hash, `any?` is likely casting each key/value pair in `r` to an array `[key, value]` and that array `r` cannot have `:ivpn` the symbol as a key (numeric only)

Comment: is there an alternative method to #any?

Comment: Probably, but I don't fully understand what the structure of `rows` is, or what values you are trying to extract from it into `representation`. Can you post a sample from `rows.inspect`?

Comment: can't you use the select method on your hash to select all keys you need/want from the source?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski rows.inspect results in => "{:ivpn =>\"\", :idirect => \"x\"}"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
representation.update_attributes! ivpn: rows.any?[{|r| r[:ivpn].present?}], idirect: rows.any? [{|r| r[:idirect].present?}]
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end; syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}'